# Admin url redirecting to localhost/admin

Tags: magento2, admin, url

Admin URL frontname is set to "admin" but on hitting the URL http://www.example.com/admin it redirects to localhost/admin

Working on localhost

`web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` is set to `http://localhost/sitename`

Using Magento 2.1.8

Comment: check web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url path value in data base core_config_data table.

Comment: so let me know on which server you working. share your server URL is it localhost or else? then I can tell you exact solution.

Comment: it is localhost. web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url path is set to http://localhost/sitename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your **Baseurl** and **Baseurl secure**

**Change From :-**

> localhost

**To** :-

> 127.0.0.1

**Then Run This Command :-**

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Finally this worked. Can you explain why this happens?

Answer (score 6):

First change from

> http://localhost/sitename

to

> http://127.0.0.1/sitename/

second, after doing this remove var/cache folder.

Comment: did the changes but it is still redirecting to localhost/admin